# Is this analysis prudent? Running several multiple regressions to gain insights

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I'm concerned that I may not be conceptualizing/applying multiple regression correctly; I would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Lets say that I'm trying to understand how to get a TV audience to watch more of my TV show.

In other words, I'm trying to influence my audience's *motivation* to watch.

A multiple linear regression has shown me that overall *enjoyment* of the show accounts for ~60% of the variance in the audience's *motivation* to keep watching. So it seems that if I increase the overall enjoyment, that will hopefully increase motivation to watch.

So how do I increase overall enjoyment? I then computed another multiple regression, which showed that a single good joke in an episode accounts for ~70% of the episode's overall enjoyment rating from the audience.

However, in my original regression, the regressor of 'single good joke' did not account for any of the variance in audience motivation.

So I have a sort of A>>B>>C situation; single good joke >> overall enjoyment >> increase motivation

Is it prudent to suggest that we should focus on producing one good joke per episode in order to increase enjoyment, and therefore increase audience motivation? I'm concerned  because 'good joke' does not directly account for 'motivation' variance, so I'm not sure if I'm being ignorant of the logic of regression.

Any tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a problem that could be solved with Structural Equation Modeling.

Comment: Was "single good joke" an IV (instrumental variable; as you state) or just a simple regressor in your original regression?

Comment: @RichardHardy 'single good joke' was just a regressor.

Comment: Could you perhaps make it clear in the question text as well? Because there *the IV of 'single good joke'* still stands. You could write "regressor" instead of "IV". It might help avoid unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Would you care to write down the regressions you used? If you have more than just the three variables that you explicitly mentioned, it could help convey the overall picture better. Perhaps the `single_good_joke` variable is jointly significant with some other variable, for example (just a guess).